# Why is "would" used in this sentence?

Tags: word-usage, conditionals, modal-verbs

I’m a passionate English-learner from Korea, and I have a question.

Why is *would* used in this sentence?

> A true friend **would** not say such a thing.

I can think that the speaker is probably not saying that a true
friend in general “doesn’t” say such a thing. So, I think maybe the
sentence means this sentence:

> If you were a true friend of mine, you wouldn’t say such a thing.

My point is that I think the “a true friend” doesn’t actually indicate
a true friend in general. I think the “a true friend” indicates the
listener. And so I think that’s why *would* is used to refer a
simple, imaginary situation. Is this why *would* is used instead
of *does* here?

I would really appreciate your help.

Comment: When you say *I think maybe the sentence means this sentence. : If you were a true friend of mine, you wouldn't say such a thing* that's exactly it - but this does not mean that  " "A true friend" doesn't actually indicates a true friend in general. I think the "A true friend" indicates the listener." It indicates a hypothetical person and the point is that the listener has not behaved like that hypothetical person i.e. *a true friend would not say X, but you did - you are not a true friend*.

Comment: it's similar to a "rhetorical question".

Answer (score 0):

I am going to expand on JD2000 comment

> When you say I think maybe the sentence means this sentence. : If you
> were a true friend of mine, you wouldn't say such a thing that's
> exactly it - but this does not mean that " "A true friend" doesn't
> actually indicates a true friend in general. I think the "A true
> friend" indicates the listener." It indicates a hypothetical person
> and the point is that the listener has not behaved like that
> hypothetical person i.e. a true friend would not say X, but you did -
> you are not a true friend. – JD2000

with an example conversation

> Pretend Friend 1: You are a miserable cow, who needs to get over your
> father's death, it was hours ago.
> Friend 2: A true friend would not say such a
> thing.

Friend 2 is saying that friend 1 is not a true friend, as no true friend would say such a mean horrible thing.

Answer (score 0):

The difference is in a sense - *would* means conditional, but *does* means present simple - that it is already happening.

Since the original sentence is rhetorical - it is not happening right now, it is more appropriate to use conditional sense, IMO.

I am not an english native, but I think that "a true friend" could actually indicate a true friend in general. But more imaginary one.

Comment: The question is about the use of *would*, not about *true friend*.  This is a comment on another answer.

Comment: I've already answered on this as well.  
I read the question as a whole, maybe you should too?